# AngularJS assigning data to variable from function

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am broadcasting my data from one controller to another.
Broadcast define in controller,

```
$rootScope.$broadcast 'dataStored', { context: array }
```

another controller which is my AngularJS NVD3 graph controller
I am receiving data using $on

```
$scope.data = []
tempStore = (event, data) ->
  array = _(data.context)
          .groupBy('name')
          .map((values,key) -> ({key,values}))
          .value()
  console.log array
$rootScope.$on 'dataStored', tempStore
console.log tempStore
```

My "console.log array" is giving me output. But how can I now assign the array data to $scope.data. I want $scope.data to have data in array variable. And last line of code "console.log tempStore" is giving me output as code defined in tempStore
I am using angularJS, coffeescript.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign array to data

```
$scope.data = array

$scope.data = []
tempStore = (event, data) => {
  var array = _(data.context)
      .groupBy('name')
      .map((values,key) => ({key,values}))
      .value()
  $scope.data = array
  console.log( $scope.data)
}
$rootScope.$on('dataStored', tempStore)
console.log tempStore
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @sridhar ... but that is not working as $scope.data is still empty

Comment: This should work, i just chnaged console statement. can you check once

Comment: I tried that @sridhar ... Within tempStore console.log is giving me output to $scope.data. But I want to use the array data outside the tempStore function. Like globally in controller.

Comment: $scope.data will be updated , only after the event is called. It will be empty before the event is called. It will be available globally now also, but by the time datastored event is called, your global code would have been executed

Comment: Execute the code you want , by calling the function inside tempStore